# How to programatically blur react bootstrap navlink?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to blur navlink after it has been clicked. My workflow is that navlink opens a modal and after the modal closes, navlink remains focused (black css). As you know blurred navlinks show grey in color.

I tried: `document.getElementById(idName).blur()` && `ref.current.blur()` . Both of those do not work. Do I have to declare custom colors and then manipulate class names for this to happen or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

```
function App() {
  const aboutLinkRef =  useRef(null);
  const navLinks= {
    ABOUT: 'ABOUT',
    LOGIN: 'LOGIN'
  }
  const [aboutModalShowState, setAboutModalShowState] = useState(false);

  const navLinkClicked = (value) => {
    if (value) {
      if (value===navLinks.ABOUT) {
        setAboutModalShowState(true);
      }
    }
  }

  const hideAboutModal = () => {
    setAboutModalShowState(false);
    document.getElementById('aboutNavLink').blur(); // does not work, 
    aboutLinkRef.current.blur(); // also does not work

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal show={aboutModalShowState} onHide={()=> hideAboutModal()}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title>About title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>About description</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={()=> hideAboutModal()}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>

      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="light" variant="light">
        <Container>
          
          <Navbar.Brand href ="/">TITLE</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
            </Nav>
            <Nav>
              <Nav.Link id='aboutNavLink' ref={aboutLinkRef} onClick={()=>navLinkClicked(navLinks.ABOUT)}>About</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link id='loginNavLink'>Login</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you add this on **codesandbox.io**, devs are willing solve your problem.